# How to find 3 or more of a character in a string?

Tags: php, string

```
$string = "oidjdssd , odi,jdois, 3089u,, oisdjsd";
```

How do i find out if theres more than 3 commas in the string above in the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest [`substr_count`](http://php.net/substr_count). You can see if the result is `>3` to see if there's more than three.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo count_chars($string)[ord(',')];
```

Or for PHP<5.4

```
$chars = count_chars($string);
echo $chars[ord(',')];
```

BTW: As it seems, that you are handling CSV-data, you should have a look at [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str-getcsv)